# What is the best way to optimize the parameters in a Sklearn classifier, when I have little data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, optimization

What is the best way to optimize the parameters in a Sklearn classifier when I only have a data set with 684 rows and 177 columns, and the column I want to predict has 3 labels?

I know I should split my data into training, validation, and test set, and then find the parameters to train the training set that maximizes a metric in the validation set and use this optimized classifier in the test set. However, when I did this using a decision tree classifier, the parameters that worked best for the validation set showed a worse result in the test set than the default parameters. So what is the best way to find the best parameters in this data set? I do not know if it helps, but my data set is very sparse.

Comment: You could look into *bagging* and *boosting*. Also, decision tree classifiers have very high variance. You could use a random forest (which aggregates decision tree classifiers to reduce variance), but I would suggest thinking about using a different model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get around the test/train thing. I guess in your case, the problem is the choice of method. When I read your data description, I suspect that you might achieve better results with regularization, e.g. Lasso. See some examples [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_and_elasticnet.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-lasso-and-elasticnet-py).

Basically you would apply a [multiclass logit with lasso penalty](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) in your case. Alternatively you could also check boosting with lasso (aka $l1$ penalty). [Here](https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/boosting_classification_iris.py) is some playcode with the iris data.

Since your data has many columns and not so many rows, I might go for lasso (not ridge or elastic net), because lasso can shrink features to zero if they don't make a meaningful contributin to the classification. This is especially helpful with high dimensional data.